# SQL WHERE Clause not filtering to criteria MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have written a query to gather the balances of two different days, find the percent difference and then display them. I added a Percent Filter section to my form to show only values that are `>=` the desired percentage.

When running the query, I get the results that are `>=` percent given. However, after the criteria is met, the results expand past and continue until `0`, as if ignoring my WHERE clause. Is there something I'm not catching within my query?

Query being used:

```
SELECT [x].[ID], [x].[Name], [x].[Day1Date], [x].[Day1Bal], [x].[Day2Date], [x].[Day2Bal], [x].[Difference], IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*100),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1)*100)) AS PerDiff

FROM qryUnion AS x

WHERE IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*100),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1)*100)) > [Forms]![Compare]![txtPercent]

ORDER BY IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*100),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1)*100)) DESC
```

I have edited and re-written my IIf statement countless times but it still doesn't filter to criteria properly.

Results (Filtered for `>=` 10%) :

```
+----------+
| PerDiff  |
+----------+
| 985.256  |
| 457.25   |
| 369.54   |
| 245.21   |
| 141.14   |
| 68.23    |
| 28.54    |
| 10.21454 |
| 10.1212  | <------- Criteria met
| 9.555    |
| 8.42     |
| 2.12     |
| 0.42     | <------- Ends at 0
+----------+
```

Obviously I'm wanting it to end at where the criteria is met, and I believe I've written my where clause to do so. I'm uncertain where else might be messing up.

`qryUnion` was a SubQuery but I had written just to get Dates and DateBals.

Any help is greatly appreciate! I'm still a bit new to SQL (and VBA for that matter). Thanks in advance!

**EDIT1:**

I have also tried

```
 WHERE IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*100),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1)*100)) >= [Forms]![Compare]![txtPercent] _ 
AND NOT IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*100),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1)*100)) < [Forms]![Compare]![txtPercent]
```

As to not show any data that is less than the given percentage. This line didn't work. Is it possible that my WHERE clause isn't the issue? I'm uncertain where else the issue may lie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ton of trouble shooting, it seems my issue was the `* 100` within my IIf statement.

SQL that worked:

```
SELECT [x].[DDANbr], [x].[Name], [x].[Day1Date], [x].[Day1Bal], [x].[Day2Date], [x].[Day2Bal], [x].[Difference], IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1))) AS PerDiff

FROM qry250CapAllCompare_Union AS x
--Added /100 at the end of WHERE clause to ensure that I was getting 10% because math
WHERE IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1)))>=Forms!frmCompare!txtPercent/100

ORDER BY IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1))) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

*A better answer may exist, but this will accomplish your goal also:

You can create a subquery for PerDiff field before writing the final query:

```
SELECT [x].[ID], [x].[Name], [x].[Day1Date], [x].[Day1Bal], [x].[Day2Date], [x].[Day2Bal], [x].[Difference], IIf(([Day2Bal]>[Day1Bal]),((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*100),(((([Day2Bal]-[Day1Bal])/[Day1Bal])*-1)*100)) AS PerDiff

FROM qryUnion AS x
```

Creating this subquery will then give you the results of the iff statement in your select clause that can then be used in the next query. So your final query could then use the Where clause like this:

```
WHERE PerDiff > [Forms]![Compare]![txtPercent]
ORDER BY PerDiff DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have already tried this, instead of it assigning the IIf statement to `PerDiff`, it requires me to input a value manually. For usability, I only want to have the Percent Filter entered once into the form, and that be taken. Having the IIf statement included three separate times is a bit annoying, but it's the only way I've found to have the functionality wanted. Of course, unless I wasn't creating the SubQuery correctly.